# Compilation error for Assert class with JUnit 5

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I added in Eclipse dependency for JUnit 5:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I compile the maven project I get multiple errors like this:

```
[ERROR] /Users/Documents/rest_api/src/test/java/org/datalis/rest/api/poc/DatabaseFeaturesIntegerTest.java:[135,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Assert
[ERROR]   location: class org.api.poc.DatabaseFeaturesIntegerTest
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Unit 5 you don't use Assert but [org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/index.html?org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html)

You can check [this tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit-5-assertions-examples/).

Comment: `junit-jupiter-engine` contains `junit-jupiter-api`

Comment: I didn't know. Thank you:)

Comment: I have fixed in my local project. Now I have I config line less:)

Comment: Good to know, @davidxxx. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I recently learned this one. Glad to share it :)

Answer (score 2):

This compilation error :

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol:   variable Assert

means that `Assert` is not resolved by the compiler and it makes sense if you would refer the JUnit `Assert` class without having previously imported it such as :

```
import org.junit.Assert;

public class DatabaseFeaturesIntegerTest { ... }
```

Note that [`org.junit.Assert`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) is for Junit 4 test classes.
For JUnit 5 test classes, you have to use [`org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/index.html?org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html).

Note that it is perfectly valid to use `org.junit.Assert` with  JUnit 5 but it should be done only as you want to compile and [run vintage JUnit test classes](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-vintage) (JUnit 4 or 3).

Comment: I also cannot find @ScenarioTest. Do you know which package I need to import?

Comment: `@ScenarioTest` is not still implemented in JUnit 5. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/13 Maybe in next versions.